# How can I export vector<T>::push_back to Python?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

This problem would be fairly simple and I would misunderstand something trivial. But since I couldn't find a solution for hours, please let me ask a question here.

What I want to do is exporting the `push_back` method of the `std::vector<T>` container class with some fixed type `T` (say `double`) to Python using Boost.Python.

To do that, I wrote the following code:

```
typedef std::vector<double> vector_double;
class_<vector_double>("vector_double")
    .def("append", &vector_double::push_back);
```

But this doesn't compile with the following error:

```
/Users/kenta/experiments/bisite/include/bisite/conservation_score.hpp:25:7: note:
      candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable:
      requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
/Users/kenta/experiments/bisite/src/bisite/pybisite.cpp:90:10: error: no
      matching member function for call to 'def'
        .def("append", &vector_double::push_back);
        ~^~~
/usr/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:234:11: note: candidate template
      ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'
    self& def(char const* name, F f)
          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:224:11: note: candidate function
      template not viable: requires single argument 'visitor', but 2 arguments
      were provided
    self& def(def_visitor<Derived> const& visitor)

... and more candidates
```

The type deduction (?) seems to fail but I can't figure out why.
When I defined `vector_double` as a subclass of `std::vector<double>`, the code above compiled successfully. But I don't want to do that for some reason.

Can you teach me a solution to this problem?

I'm using clang++ with `-std=c++11` option and Boost.Python v1.56.0.

Thank you.

Comment: It should be noted that Boost.Python already has the [`vector_indexing_suite`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html#vector_indexing_suite), which is made specifically for exposing an `std::vector`.

Comment: I thought that `vector_indexing_suite` adds indexing related methods only as the name suggests, but actually it also adds the `append` and `extend` methods!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that problem is, that there is two version of [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) in C++11.
Try to do it this way

```
static_cast<void (vector_double::*)(const double&)>(&vector_double::push_back);
```

Comment: Your solution completely solved the problem. Thanks! But Paul's solution was sufficient and idiomatic.